# Select Word Doc using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to create Excel VBA code that asks the user to open a pre-existing Word document with text form fields and input existing Excel data in these form fields.

I have code that writes the Excel data into the Word text form field.

```vb
Sub NewMacro()    

    Dim wdApp As Object, wd As Object, ac As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Tables")

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Test\Test.docx")

    wdApp.Visible = True

    With wd
        .FormFields("CustomerName").Result = ws.Range("D4").Value
    End With

    Set wd = Nothing

    Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am lost as to converting the `Set wd= wdApp.Documents.Open("FilePath")` line into a dialog box.

Does a function exist where the user can select the file by clicking through Windows Explorer as opposed to typing the path?

Comment: `Application.GetOpenFileName`

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/editing-word-doc-using-excel-vba.1118161/. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the user to input the name of a Word file? Do you want the [InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) method?

```
    Dim strWord As String
    strWord = InputBox(prompt:="Type the file path and name of the Word file.", title:="Which file?", default:="C:\Path\File.docx")
    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Open(strWord)
```

Tell me if I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly right. Does a function exist where the user can select the file by clicking through windows explorer as opposed to typing the path?